Let's get critical: Oct 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love LEGO® Answers, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Preparations for outside display

Net Score: 6 (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


I need information on LEGO part #3001 in Milky White with Sparkles

Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is it possible to connect EV3 and NXT bricks like master/slave configuration via bluetooth?

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)


Need help to identify minifigure

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)


What is this model number please?

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)


How to build an automatic Lego train system?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)


I bought a second hand pack of pieces and it looks like it may be a specific set

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)


How to make NXT bricks communicate information?

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)


What set does this minifigure head come from?

Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 4)


What part can I use to get the connection

Net Score: -3 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)


My first thought is that this survey had a relatively small number of responses, and as such we shouldn't over-emphasise the value of the results. On the other hand, this data certainly provide food for thought, particularly as it is likely to represent the views of the more dedicated users of this site.
I have just a couple of observations:


What part can I use to get the connection

Net Score: -3
In my view (and with the benefit of hindsight) I think that this question should have been put on hold until it was clarified. I am still not quite sure what it is asking, and link-rot would make the question completely unintelligible. (I mean no disrespect to the questioner: it can be hard to ask good questions, and I doubt that I could have done better in this case).


whose head is this in this picture?

Net Score: -3
To be honest, I struggle to see why this is any worse than

Need help to identify minifigure

Net Score: 2
In general, part identification seems like a perfect fit for this site. That said, it would be nice if the titles of the questions were more descriptive so we can distinguish them more easily as the site gets bigger. For example "Identification of head with nauseated expression".
But still, why did the first of these questions score so much worse than the second?

While I agree it's a low number of responses, it's quite a lot more than we've had for the last 3 or 4 evaluations (Apr 2014: 4, Jan 2013: 4, Oct 2013: 6) ;)

In terms of the specific questions you're commenting on: "Connection" - agree this is particularly poorly crafted question, however it has got a fairly good response, but both Q and A could use some additional images detailing the issue.

Why is "Whose head" worse than "Need help" - The second one explained how they found the part in question rather than just supplying the answer, "teach a person to fish" and all that. Obviously those are my opinions and others may well be available ;)
